# Chang color of RowCell Banded Gridview Devexpress

Tags: c#, visual-studio, devexpress

I followed this post [Create BandedGridView for DevExpress XtraGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16717322/create-bandedgridview-for-devexpress-xtragrid) to generate bands dinamically but i need to change the color of a cell but the RowCellStyle event doesn't fireup

Comment: have you bind event with event handler?? means subscribed these events?? GridView.RowCellStyle += someHandler

Comment: i try to do this 
        DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.RowCellStyleEventArgs RowStyleEventArgs = default(DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.RowCellStyleEventArgs);
            bandedGridView1_RowCellStyle(bandedGridView1, RowStyleEventArgs);
but when it fires the event, i have this code in the event but i have a null reference exception when i try to access to e.ColumnName
if (e.Column.Name == "COLUM NAME") 
{
   e.Appearance.BackColor = Color.DeepSkyBlue;
   e.Appearance.BackColor2 = Color.LightCyan;
}

Answer (score 0):

Implement [CustomDrawCell event](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridView_CustomDrawCelltopic) and change the color there.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but my problem is the events doesn't fire! the only event that fire's up is rowstyle

Comment: Do you need to "wire up" your event. Something like `bandedGridView1.CustomDrawCell += bandedGridView1_CustomDrawCell;`

Comment: the event doesn't fire with that method